# Question about multimeter resolution

Tags: voltage, dc, multimeter, voltage-measurement, resolution

So i got a multimeter from a friend for free. This is the one:

[Multimeter Info](http://uni-trend.com/UT33A.html)

In the manual of the multimeter it says that the lowest resolution of DC Voltage is 0.1 mV. does that mean that i can measure all the way down to 0.1 mV (0.0001V)
or am i getting this wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Theoretically that is true, but at 0.8% best accuracy, I wouldn't trust the reading that much. It's the difference between resolution and accuracy. It's got the resolution but not enough accuracy to make good use of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically yes with some restrictions.  The lowest range is 400 mv and the meter has a full scale of 3999 counts.  That means that on the 400 mv range, the least significant digit is indeed 0.1 mv.  However, internal noise or external pickup may limit being able to actually measure a voltage that low. Also,  there is a minimum accuracy of plus or minus 1 count which represents 0.1 mv on the 400 mv scale.  Thus the actual voltage could be 0.2 mv for a 100% error.

Comment: Actually that is the -Best Accuracy-... no guarantee it is for the 400mV range. Though generally the point is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct, it means that it's minimum measurement of voltage that can be displayed on the screen is 0.1mV.
It may not actually reflect the quality / accuracy of the device however but assuming it is accurate then it will be able to measure down to 0.1mV yes.